# If $AB^∗$ and $B^∗A$ are both normal, show that $B A^∗A = A A^∗B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-analysis

This might be an easy question, but I haven't been able to prove it.

Prove that if $A B^*$ and $B^* A$ are normal matrices, then $B A^* A = A A^* B$

Any help is appreciated.

Here, $A^*$ is the conjugate transpose of $A$

Comment: What is the star in BA$\ast$A and AA$\ast$B in the title? Is it $A^{\ast}$? What have you tried?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I have clarified the notation in the question.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I couldn't find a suitable title. Kindly ignore that.

Comment: Are you assuming your matrices to be real-valued?

Comment: @Sven-OleBehrend No.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows form the Fuglede-Putnam-Rosenblum Theorem (which istn't trivial) that states: If $X$ and $Y$ are normal matrices and $Z$ is any matrix with $XZ=ZY$, then $X^\ast Z = ZY^\ast$. In case of the question set $X=AB^\ast$, $Y=B^\ast A$ and $Z=A$. Then $XZ = AB^\ast A = ZY$, so $BA^\ast A=X^\ast Z =ZY^\ast= A A^\ast B$.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.